# Unable to locate libjson-rpc-config.cmake after installing it via apt-get

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-16.04, apt-get

I have a CMakeList which includes libjson-rpc-cpp like this:

`find_package(libjson-rpc-cpp REQUIRED)`

To install it I execute the command:

```
apt-get install libjsonrpccpp-dev libjsonrpccpp-tools
```

However, I still get the error message, that find_package files cause it cannot find anof the following names:

```
libjson-rpc-config.cmake
libjson-rpc-cpp-config.cmake
```

The version of libjson-rpc-cpp is `0.6.0-2build1`, the cmake version is `3.5.1`, I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

When I execute the command

```
dpkg -L libjsonrpccpp-dev
```

I get the paths to where the lib was installed to (`.a` and `.so` files to `/usr/lib/x86_64_gnu`,  headers to `/usr/include/jsonrpccp` and `.gz` and copyright to `/usr/share/doc/libjsonrpccpp-dev`

I read that the package was renamed, after 15.04 , do I need to change the name, too? And if so, to what?